# How to boost up post request in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, post

```
import requests
import csv

url= ['exmpale.com']
header = {'1234567'}

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   for row in reader:
      print(row)
      requests.post(url, json=row, headers=header)
```

Hi, I'm new here. My code above able to post the data to my server side around 5 seconds per record. It still acceptable If my data is within hundred of records but not in millions of records. How can I boot up the post request?

Updated using grequest

```
    import csv
    import grequests

    url= ['exmpale.com']
    header = {'1234567'}

    with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       for row in reader:
          print(row)
          rs = [ grequests.post(u, json=row, headers=header) for u in url]

          grequests.map(rs)
```

Comment: Where is your server? Where is your client? Have you checked how long the server is taking for the response (by checking the server logs)?

Comment: I try to use this example `post = request.post` then `print(post.text)`. The server response 4-5 seconds for each record

Comment: You could be suffering from: 1) a really slow server. 2) a really slow network. 3) latency 4) any combination of the above

Comment: I think it's hard to track those unpredict problem.  Is there any way to improve the code to reduce this kind of problems?

Comment: It's hard - I agree. But you see, if you server takes 5 secs to respond to a request, you can speed up the client as much as you'd like but you'll still be limited to 5 secs per request. The easiest thing for you to do at the client side is to parallelize the requests - or make them async. But if the problem is with the server that might aggravate things due to the increased load

Comment: I updated my code which using the `grequest`. It seems support the async. But the speed doesn't change too much because of the target url is only one?

Comment: You should definitely check if that server is slow or not before making more code changes.

Comment: @DroidX86 I believe my server-side is fast enough to handle the large request. I did try to move other location which has higher internet speed but it still remains the same.